Tkinter - How to check a buttons' state; repeat for multiple buttons, and total the results?
I have made a digital version of a pen-and-paper game as my first major python practice project. You can see from the attached picture that the main board consists of buttons. They can be toggled between two states: they start displaying a number and are True, when clicked they display an "X" and become False. You will see from the screenshot that there is a score multiplier that tells you how many points you get for each row depending on how many buttons are displaying "X", i.e. in the False state.
At the moment the user has to enter the score manually for each row. What I'm trying to do is have the appropriate score appear in the appropriate box depending on the number of buttons that are False. For example, if four red buttons have been clicked, so are False, 10 would be displayed in the red Score box.
The help I am seeking: I do not know how to check the current boolean state of each button, nor do I know how to total the results.
I am very new to programming and am learning for fun. I do not want or expect a whole program to be written for me that I can copy and paste; I would like to be pointed in the right direction.

I have included below just the code relevent to the main board (the 4 coloured rows) and the score boxes. Below I have included the code for just the red row of the main board, and the score boxes.
import tkinter                       
import tkinter.messagebox          

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        
        # Window setup
        self.window = tkinter.Tk() 
        self.window.title("Quixx")
        self.window.geometry("600x400")
        self.window.maxsize(600, 400)
        self.window.minsize(600, 400)
        

        # Main board function variables
        self.state1 = True
        self.state2 = True
        self.state3 = True
        self.state4 = True
        self.state5 = True
        self.state6 = True
        self.state7 = True
        self.state8 = True
        self.state9 = True
        self.state10 = True
        self.state11 = True
        # Removed for brevity.
 

# Main board setup.
        button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(8, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(9, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
        button_frame.columnconfigure(11, weight=1)

        # Red row
        self.btn1 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="2", background="red", command=self.btn1_change)
        self.btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="we",)
        
        self.btn2 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="3", background="red", command=self.btn2_change)
        self.btn2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn3 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="4", background="red", command=self.btn3_change)
        self.btn3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn4 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="5", background="red", command=self.btn4_change)
        self.btn4.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn5 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="6", background="red", command=self.btn5_change)
        self.btn5.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn6 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="7", background="red", command=self.btn6_change)
        self.btn6.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn7 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="8", background="red", command=self.btn7_change)
        self.btn7.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn8 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="9", background="red", command=self.btn8_change)
        self.btn8.grid(row=0, column=7, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn9 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="10", background="red", command=self.btn9_change)
        self.btn9.grid(row=0, column=8, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn10 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="11", background="red", command=self.btn10_change)
        self.btn10.grid(row=0, column=9, sticky="we")
        
        self.btn11 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="12", background="red", command=self.btn11_change)
        self.btn11.grid(row=0, column=10, sticky="we")

        

        # Yellow row
          # removed for brevity

        # Green row
          # removed for brevity

        # Blue row
          # removed for brevity
        

# Score calculation frame setup
        score_calc_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(8, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(9, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
        score_calc_frame.columnconfigure(11, weight=1)

        # Score labels and textboxes
        self.score_calc_label1 = tkinter.Label(score_calc_frame, text="Score", font=('arial', 16))
        self.score_calc_label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="we")

        self.score_calc_textbox_red = tkinter.Text(score_calc_frame, height=1, width=1, background="red")
        self.score_calc_textbox_red.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="we",)

        self.score_calc_label2 = tkinter.Label(score_calc_frame, text="+", font=('Arial', 18))
        self.score_calc_label2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="we")

        self.score_calc_textbox_yellow = tkinter.Text(score_calc_frame, height=1, width=1, background="yellow")
        self.score_calc_textbox_yellow.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="we")

        self.score_calc_label3 = tkinter.Label(score_calc_frame, text="+", font=('arial', 18))
        self.score_calc_label3.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="we")

        self.score_calc_textbox_green = tkinter.Text(score_calc_frame, height=1, width=1, background="green")
        self.score_calc_textbox_green.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="we")

        self.score_calc_label4 = tkinter.Label(score_calc_frame, text="+", font=('arial', 18))
        self.score_calc_label4.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky="we")

        self.score_calc_textbox_blue = tkinter.Text(score_calc_frame, height=1, width=1, background="blue")
        self.score_calc_textbox_blue.grid(row=0, column=7, sticky="we")

        self.score_calc_label5 = tkinter.Label(score_calc_frame, text="-", font=('arial', 18))
        self.score_calc_label5.grid(row=0, column=8, sticky="we")

        self.score_calc_textbox_subtract = tkinter.Text(score_calc_frame, height=1, width=1)
        self.score_calc_textbox_subtract.grid(row=0, column=9, sticky="we")

        self.score_calc_label6 = tkinter.Label(score_calc_frame, text="=", font=('arial', 18))
        self.score_calc_label6.grid(row=0, column=10, sticky="we")

        self.score_calc_label_result = tkinter.Label(score_calc_frame, height=1, width=1, background="white")
        self.score_calc_label_result.grid(row=0, column=11, sticky="we")

        
    # Main board button frame packing
        button_frame.pack(fill="x", anchor="n", padx=10, pady=20)
    
    # Score calculation frame packing
        score_calc_frame.pack(fill="x", padx=5, anchor="center")

        self.window.mainloop()

# Main board button functions
  
    # Red row
    def btn1_change(self):
        if self.state1 == True:
            self.btn1.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn1.config(text="2")
        self.state1 = not self.state1
            
    def btn2_change(self):
        if self.state2 == True:
            self.btn2.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn2.config(text="3")
        self.state2 = not self.state2 

    def btn3_change(self):
        if self.state3 == True:
            self.btn3.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn3.config(text="4")
        self.state3 = not self.state3

    def btn4_change(self):
        if self.state4 == True:
            self.btn4.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn4.config(text="5")
        self.state4 = not self.state4 

    def btn5_change(self):
        if self.state5 == True:
            self.btn5.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn5.config(text="6")
        self.state5 = not self.state5 

    def btn6_change(self):
        if self.state6 == True:
            self.btn6.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn6.config(text="7")
        self.state6 = not self.state6 

    def btn7_change(self):
        if self.state7 == True:
            self.btn7.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn7.config(text="8")
        self.state7 = not self.state7 

    def btn8_change(self):
        if self.state8 == True:
            self.btn8.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn8.config(text="9")
        self.state8 = not self.state8 

    def btn9_change(self):
        if self.state9 == True:
            self.btn9.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn9.config(text="10")
        self.state9 = not self.state9 

    def btn10_change(self):
        if self.state10 == True:
            self.btn10.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn10.config(text="11")
        self.state10 = not self.state10 

    def btn11_change(self):
        if self.state11 == True:
            self.btn11.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn11.config(text="12")
        self.state11 = not self.state11 

    
    
    
    # Yellow row
      # removed for brevity 
    
    # Green row
      # removed for brevity   
    
    # Blue row
      # removed for brevity

MyGUI()

And this is the code that I thought looked most promising from my research on how to solve this, but I'm unsure how to implement it:
def btn1_change(self):
        c=0
        for i in self.red_row_list:
            if(i==False):
                c+=1
        return c


Given that you save the state in various fields (state1, state2 etc.) you would have to check one by one:
    def btn1_change(self):
        if self.state1 == True:
            self.btn1.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn1.config(text="2")
        self.state1 = not self.state1
        c = 0
        if not self.state1:
            c += 1
        if not self.state2:
            c += 1
        if not self.state3:
            c += 1
        if not self.state4:
            c += 1
        if not self.state5:
            c += 1
        if not self.state6:
            c += 1
        if not self.state7:
            c += 1
        if not self.state8:
            c += 1
        if not self.state9:
            c += 1
        if not self.state10:
            c += 1
        if not self.state11:
            c += 1
        self.score_calc_textbox_red.replace('1.0', tkinter.END, c)

Not only that, you would have to execute this in every callback, so you would either repeat this code or (preferably) move it to a function to be called from every button.
But there are may ways in which it can be improved. Here I will suggest one improvement:
You can reduce this amount of code by saving the state in a list, instead of having one field per state:
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):

        # Window setup
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.title("Quixx")
        self.window.geometry("600x400")
        self.window.maxsize(600, 400)
        self.window.minsize(600, 400)


        # Main board function variables
        # Here we create a list with eleven True values
        self.state = [True] * 11

    def btn1_change(self):
        if self.state[0] == True:
            self.btn1.config(text="X")
        else:
            self.btn1.config(text="2")
        self.state[0] = not self.state[0]
        c = 0
        for s in self.state:
            # In general `not s` is preferable for `s == False`
            if not s:
                c += 1
        self.score_calc_textbox_red.replace('1.0', tkinter.END, c)

Of course, much more could be changed, but since you are still learning, I believe there is enough here for you to unpack. Good luck!

Hi, thanks for your answer. I really like the use of lists for the variables, I didn't realize lists could be used in that way. I am experimenting with using lists in my program and have run into a problem.  My program has a reset function that resets all the buttons to the true state and resets their text. I'm trying to reset all the values in the list to True using for self.s in self.state: self.s = True , but it doesn't actually reset the button states, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Good to know you liked it! You may use lists even more, for example, to store the buttons themselves. But since you are learning, you can  proceed at your pace. As of your for loop, it will not work, first because self.s is not a valid variable name and second because you would only set the variable, not change the value of the list. You can check this answer and, If you have doubts, you should post a new question.

Try this:
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

        # Main board setup. Store the frame as an attribute of this class to access later.
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        self.button_frame.columnconfigure(list(range(12)), weight=1)  # Gives all 12 columns an equal weight of 1

        self.btn1 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="2", background="red", command=self.btn1_change)
        self.btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="we",)
        
        self.btn2 = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="3", background="red", command=self.btn2_change)
        self.btn2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="we")

        # Rest of buttons, removed for brevity
        ...

        # Main board button frame packing
        self.button_frame.pack(fill="x", anchor="n", padx=10, pady=20)

    # Main board button functions, removed for brevity
    ...

    # Will need to be called anytime a red button is clicked, implementation details left out on request of OP
    def red_buttons_clicked(self):
        clicked = 0
        
        # Iterate through a list of the buttons using `.grid_slaves()`
        # Filter the list to get buttons in the 0th row (which represents the red buttons) by passing the argument `row=0`
        # Can also be filtered by column with the `column` argument
        for button in self.button_frame.grid_slaves(row=0):
            # Check the value of the text (which represents our state) with `.cget("text")`
            if button.cget("text") == "X":
                clicked += 1

        return clicked


Thanks for your contribution! Check out [answer] - answers are at their best when they contain an explanation in addition to the code alone.

@AndrewYim The explanation is included in the code as comments

Ah, I missed that - my bad! Might still be nice to have a quick summary at the top, but that's totally up to you.
